# How can I get data from mysql database into datatable with doctrine (Symfony 4)?

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, datatable, doctrine

Like this my table is filled data from an Array:

```
  public function showAction(Request $request)
  {

    $table = $this->createDataTable()
    ->add('firstName', TextColumn::class)
    ->add('lastName', TextColumn::class)
    ->createAdapter(ArrayAdapter::class, [
      ['firstName' => 'Cat', 'lastName' => 'Duck'],
      ['firstName' => 'Monkey', 'lastName' => 'Dog'],
    ])
    ->handleRequest($request);

    if ($table->isCallback()) {
      return $table->getResponse();
    }

    return $this->render('list.html.twig', ['datatable' => $table]);
  }
```

But what I need is to get the data directly from the mySQL database. I tried this with doctrine:

```
 public function showAction(Request $request)
  {
    $articles = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Article::class)->findAll()->handleRequest($request);

    if ($articles ->isCallback()) {
      return $articles ->getResponse();
    }

    return $this->render('list.html.twig', ['datatable' => $articles]);
  }
```

But I get an ERROR:

> Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: "Call to a member function handleRequest() on array" at /Users/work/project/src/Controller/DataTableController.php line 27

I also tried to write it like this:

```
  public function showAction(Request $request)
  {
    $articles = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Article::class)->findAll();

    return $this->render('list.html.twig', ['datatable' => $articles]);
  }
```

But here I get the error:

> Argument 1 passed to
>   Omines\DataTablesBundle\Twig\DataTablesExtension::Omines\DataTablesBundle\Twig{closure}()
>   must be an instance of Omines\DataTablesBundle\DataTable, array given,
>   called in
>   /Users/work/project/var/cache/dev/twig/0b/0bf4881c934fbecf72f2dfcacd298733196c8daa0e22d77f67fcdf0fee9f33e4.php
>   on line 185

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to documentation (https://omines.github.io/datatables-bundle/#doctrine-orm)

In your first exemple, you need to do this :

```
public function showAction(Request $request)
{
    $table = $this->createDataTable()
    ->add('firstName', TextColumn::class)
    ->add('lastName', TextColumn::class)
    ->createAdapter(ORMAdapter::class, [
        'entity' => Article::class,
    ])
    ->handleRequest($request);

    if ($table->isCallback()) {
        return $table->getResponse();
    }

    return $this->render('list.html.twig', ['datatable' => $table]);
}
```

Don't forget to add this on top of your class :

```
use Omines\DataTablesBundle\Adapter\Doctrine\ORMAdapter;
```

Comment: This was a perfect help